# Receiving chat notifications in inbox even after seeing message and replying instantly

Tags: bug, chat

Here is a [message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29257014#29257014) in chat addressed to me, to which I [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=29257023#29257023) within a minute or so, as shown by [their](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/29257014/history) [histories](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/29257023/history):

[image: message and reply]

But I still received a notification for it in my global inbox a while later:

[image: notification]

This has been happening over the past few weeks randomly. Not commonly, but not rarely either.

UA: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0`. No extensions or userscripts which interfere with the page DOM.

I hope the red free-hand marks are aesthetic enough to give me lots of upvotes.

Comment: -1 Not enough jQuery

Comment: It always happened to me, rarely (i.e. less than 1% of the times). Was never able to track it down and it's quite minor, so didn't report.

Comment: It always happened to me, commonly (i.e. 90% of the time). Didn't try to track it down, and didn't report it.